# Excel VBA - Subscript out of range - Sheets name as a variable

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to work on a Worksheet whose name is a variable.

I have a main sheet, called "data" where I go to catch a list of names of existing sheets.

My code is as follows :

```
Dim data as Worksheet
dim sheet_name as String
Dim i as Integer
Set data = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Data")

For i = 2 to 10
    sheet_name = data.Range("A"&i).Value
    With ThisWorkbook.Sheets(sheet_name)
        'Operations on the worksheet
    End With
Next i
```

The error prompted is "Runtime Error 9 : Subscript Out of Range" for the specific line :

```
With This Workbook.Sheets(sheet_name)
```

It is as if the object Sheets didn't understand the string sheet_name.
The Sheet "sheet_name" exists for sure, I double-checked.

Unfortunately, I cannot call the sheet by its name because I have too many sheets to operate on, this is why I wanted to do a loop.

I tried not working with the "With" clause but just referring to every object of the sheets with "ThisWorkbook.Sheets(sheet_name) in front but doesn't work either.

Do you know if it is possible to call a string variable inside a Sheets()?

Thanks a lot for your help !

Kind regards,

Comment: It's possible to do what you want - it looks like there is no sheet matching the value of `sheet_name` though.

Comment: Should it be `With sheet_name ... End With`?

Comment: Your code definitely works _provided_ the list of names on sheet `Data` _exactly_ match the sheet names (they are case insensitive).  Check for things like extra spaces on the beginning or end of the names (both in `data` and actual sheet names).  Any blanks in `Data!A2:A10` will also cause this error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason for your error was given in the comments above by @chris neilsen

You could use the code below to check or avoid having these kind of errors:

```
Option Explicit

Sub CheckShtExists()

Dim data As Worksheet
Dim sheet_name As String

Set data = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Data")

Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim ShtNamesArr() As String
Dim i As Long

ReDim ShtNamesArr(0 To ThisWorkbook.Worksheets.Count - 1) ' resize array to number of worksheets in This Workbook

' loop thourgh all worksheets and store their names in array
For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
    ShtNamesArr(i) = ws.Name
    i = i + 1
Next ws

For i = 2 To 10
    If data.Range("A" & i).Value <> "" Then ' ignore blank cells
        sheet_name = data.Range("A" & i).Value
        If Not IsError(Application.Match(sheet_name, ShtNamesArr, 0)) Then ' use Application.Match to see there is a sheet with this name
            With ThisWorkbook.Sheets(sheet_name)
                'Operations on the worksheet
            End With
        Else ' No Match
            MsgBox sheet_name & " doesn't exists in your workbook"
        End If
    End If
Next i

End Sub
```